# Wallet won't open, error loading libXtst.so.6

Tags: wallets

When I try to open the Ethereum wallet in Elementary OS (Ubuntu) I get the error

> Ethereum Wallet: error while loading shared libraries: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libxtst6 is installed, any ideas?

Comment: 1: is it 23/64b? 2-what do you get with :  locate libXtst

Comment: gives me: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0

Comment: did you install the 32 or 64 b version

Comment: Ah, I installed the 32bit version and not 64bit. Silly mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to install the 32 version of the libxtst

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

then make a symbolic link :

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ ln -s libXtst.so.6 libXtst.so.6.X.X
```

or just install the [64 bit](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/download/v0.8.5/Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-8-5.deb) version of Ethereum.